# How to exclude all rows where a column value is different but other columns are the same

Tags: t-sql

So many similar questions - mainly the questions are about how to select one of the duplicates where only a single column is different, but I want to exclude all of them from a query, and only get the ones where a particular field isn't different.

I am looking for all the `reference_no` where the status is -1, except for those where the status is both -1 and 1 for the same reference_no, as in the table below. The query should return only row Id 4. How do I do that?

This is using SQL server 2016

```
| id  | process_date | status | reference_no |
| --- | ------------ | ------ | -----------  |
| 1   | 12/5/22      | 1      | 789456       |
| 2   | 12/5/22      | -1     | 789456       |
| 3   | 12/5/22      | 1      | 789456       |
| 4   | 12/5/22      | 1      | 321654       |
```

Comment: If you want status where it's -1, why is Row 4 expected?

Comment: Because the reference_no is a duplicate. The purpose of the status field is to say whether a particular run was successful or not. If it ran three times, but was both successful and unsuccessful, I don't want any of those results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want a *not exists* check

```
select *
from t
where status = -1 
and not exists (
  select * from t t2 
  where t2.status = 1 and t2.reference_no = t.reference_no
);
```

Comment: thank you! I had been close to this at one point, but the where clause is what got me.